# How to calculate the sum of all the numbers from a string like "10+5+6+31+3+45" in c

Tags: c

> I found this code but this sum all the digits but i want it to ad 31 not 3+1
> Output : 28
> Expected : 100

```
#include<stdio.h>  
int main()
{
    //Initializing variables.
    char str[100] = "10+5+6+31+3+45";
    int i,sum = 0;
    
    //Iterating each character through for loop.
    for (i= 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] >= '0') && (str[i] <= '9'))  //Checking for numeric characters.
        {
            
            sum += (str[i] - '0'); //Adding numeric characters.

        }
    }
    //Printing result.
    printf("Sum of all digits:\n%d", sum);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `28` is the sum of the digits. `100` is the sum of the numbers. Please attempt to modify the "code you found" yourself, and then ask about problems. The code you found is the wrong code.

Comment: Your logic for you are trying to do is quite incorrect.  You are right now adding up just the 'ASCII' code values of just the charadters '0' to '9' and skipping over the '+' which is going to add up to 28 (e.g.) '4' + '5' ... hint 1: use the '+' to figure out the units and tens etc. to figure it out.  hint 2: use a separate function to do this.  

If you have trouble with this, I'll post a partial solution :) to help guide you along

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the delimiter apparently is the plus sign, you might utilize the "strkok" string function as noted in the following link [strkok example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm).

Utilizing that method with your initial code resulted in the following code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //Initializing variables.
    char str[100] = "10+5+6+31+3+45";
    int sum = 0;
    char *token;
    const char s[2] = "+";

    /* get the first token */
    token = strtok(str, s);

    /* walk through other tokens */
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        sum = sum + atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
    //Printing result.
    printf("Sum of all numbers is: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Testing this code resulted in the following terminal output.

```
Sum of all numbers is: 100

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.035 s
Press any key to continue.
```

You might try this route to see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: The concept here  is well presented, and as far as teaching the concept goes, the clarity obtained by not cluttering the code with excessive safeties like checking the return value before using the value or ensuring a complete delimiter list, provides the student with an unobstructed presentation of concept.  However, a disclaimer detailing at least in words the danger of implementing code like this for anything other than concept illustration would be at least as valuable to your student as the central concept itself.  +1 for the concept, but consider adding some cautions on implementation.

Answer (score 1):

We can iterate backwards through the string and add up all the digits, except a digit that we see after another digit is worth 10x more, because it is in a more significant position in the number.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char str[] = "10+5+6+31+3+45";

  unsigned int sum = 0;
  unsigned int digit_value = 1;

  unsigned int length = strlen(str);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    char c = str[length - 1 - i];
    if (c == '+') {
      digit_value = 1;
    }
    else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
      sum += digit_value * (c - '0');
      digit_value *= 10;
    }
  }

  printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
}
```

This is a very specialized parser that is designed to just handle your specific type of problem.  As soon as you add any complications (like minus signs), this parser would likely have to be re-written.

Comment: Yes, they are. “Answers” that just give a student something to turn in for their homework exercise without actually answering a question (implied or asked) about **how** to solve a problem are not good answers and should be voted down. Showing code is not answering how to write the code. It is bad for the student and bad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void add_up(const char *in, char *out, size_t ndig)
{
  size_t dig = ndig;
  for (size_t i = strlen(in); i-- > 0; )
  {
    int ch = in[i];

    if (isdigit((unsigned char) ch)) {
      size_t j = dig;
      if (j == 0)
        goto overflow;
      out[--j] += (ch - '0');
      while (j >= 1 && out[j] > '9') {
        out[j] -= 10;
        out[--j]++;
      }
      if (out[j] > '9') {
      overflow:
        fputs("overflow\n", stderr);
        abort();
      }
      dig--;
    } else if (ch == '+') {
      dig = ndig;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char *self = argv[0] ? argv[0] : "unknown";
  char sum[] = "00000000";

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: argument required\n", self);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  add_up(argv[1], sum, sizeof sum - 1);
  puts(sum);
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -W -Wall -O2 strsum.c -o strsum
$ ./sumstr 1
00000001
$ ./sumstr 10
00000010
$ ./sumstr 1000
00001000
$ ./sumstr 10000
00010000
$ ./sumstr 100000
00100000
$ ./sumstr 1000000
01000000
$ ./sumstr 10000000
10000000
$ ./sumstr 100000000
overflow
Aborted (core dumped)
$ ./sumstr 1+2
00000003
$ ./sumstr 1+2+3
00000006
$ ./sumstr 1+2+3+4
00000010
$ ./sumstr 1+2+3+4+1000
00001010
$ ./sumstr 1+2+3+4+1000+13300
00014310
$ ./sumstr 1+2+3+4+1000+13300+1
00014311
$ ./sumstr 1+2+3+4+1000+13300+1+900000
00914311
$ ./sumstr 1+2+3+4+1000+13300+1+9000000
09014311
```

In this program, we have rely only on arithmetic of characters. We begin with the character string `00000000` (eight zeros: easily extended), and treat that as a counter which we increment by the values of the successive elements from the input string such as `1+2+3`.

We scan the input string backwards. For instance, suppose that the string ends with `+23`. We first visit the 3:

```
00000000
       3
       ^
```

we increment the last digit of our string by the numeric value of that digit, which is `'3' - '0'`. Next, we encounter the `2` of `23`, remembering that we are working backwards:

```
00000003
      2
      ^
```

We add the value of the digit `2` to the second digit in the string:

```
00000023
```

Next, we see the `+` character in `+23`. That means we will reset our digit position; the next time we see a digit, we add it to the ones column. Suppose the input ends with `+9+23`. The next digit we will process is `9`:

```
00000023
       9
       ^
```

When we increment the digit `3` by 9, we get the `<` ASCII character:

```
0000002<
```

This character is beyond `9`, so we have overflow. To handle this, we subtract 10, and carry a 1 into the next column.

```
      1
00000022
```

and so our accumulator becomes:

```
00000032
```

Comment: That's kind of fun that you are doing addition using decimal strings.  I made my own version that uses `argv[1]` as both the input buffer and the output buffer, so there will never be an overflow no matter how long the input is.  https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/e85901f557b97cb4fcd2cc45a11ad201

Comment: @DavidGrayson Nice. By the way, ISO C requires the `argv[]` strings to be mutable, so it is fine. (However, the pointer array is not required to be mutable, so something like `argv[1] = "foo"` is undefined behavior.)

Comment: @DavidGrayson A challenge would be to handle subtractions. We could do it like like this: do a left-to-right scan of the input string. Replace every sequence of digits which is `-{digits}` with `+{digits}-`, then handle the minus in the algorithm. That of course makes the string longer so you can't do it by mutating the input in place. However, by identifying some way of encoding the trailing minus together with the last digit into one byte, we can preserve the length.

Comment: @Kaz OK, yeah, I implemented something like that but it's not very elegant because it requires 5 loops through the string:  https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/e85901f557b97cb4fcd2cc45a11ad201#file-crazy_sum_with_minus-c